# Error when the application is compiled in android studio?

Tags: android, compiler-errors

Created in Android Studio project produces an error, the error stack below. An error popped up after the creation of a custom Nawigation Drawer Activity.What could it be?

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.support.v4.view.AccessibilityDelegateCompatIcs$AccessibilityDelegateBridge
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ProjectClassLoader.load(ProjectClassLoader.java:112)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderClassLoader.findClass(RenderClassLoader.java:52)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ProjectClassLoader.findClass(ProjectClassLoader.java:73)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at android.support.v4.view.AccessibilityDelegateCompat.<clinit>(AccessibilityDelegateCompat.java:296)
at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.<init>(DrawerLayout.java:162)
at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.<init>(DrawerLayout.java:256)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.createNewInstance(ViewLoader.java:379)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadView(ViewLoader.java:99)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.LayoutlibCallback.loadView(LayoutlibCallback.java:172)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:207)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:132)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:478)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:381)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:400)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:329)
at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:333)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService$5.compute(RenderService.java:674)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService$5.compute(RenderService.java:663)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:932)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService.createRenderSession(RenderService.java:663)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService.render(RenderService.java:790)
at com.intellij.android.designer.designSurface.AndroidDesignerEditorPanel$6.run(AndroidDesignerEditorPanel.java:480)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:320)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:310)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue$2.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:254)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:269)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:227)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:217)
at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor.runSafely(QueueProcessor.java:238)
at com.intellij.util.Alarm$Request$1.run(Alarm.java:327)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

There is my xml where I get error:

```
<!-- A DrawerLayout is intended to be used as the top-level content view using match_parent for both width and height to consume the full space available. -->
```

```
<!-- As the main content view, the view below consumes the entire
     space available using match_parent in both dimensions. -->
<FrameLayout android:id="@+id/container" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<!-- android:layout_gravity="start" tells DrawerLayout to treat
     this as a sliding drawer on the left side for left-to-right
     languages and on the right side for right-to-left languages.
     If you're not building against API 17 or higher, use
     android:layout_gravity="left" instead. -->
<!-- The drawer is given a fixed width in dp and extends the full height of
     the container. -->
<fragment android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:name="com.tvitbook.dd.tvitbook.NavigationDrawerFragment"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />
```

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WyFxX.png)

Comment: Sorry for my English,I from Ukrainian)

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you don't have the required Compatibility Library (android.support.v4). If that's the case, add it to your project following the [docs](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html#add-library):

> 1. Make sure you have downloaded the Android Support Repository using the SDK Manager.
> 2. Open the build.gradle file for your application.
> 3. Add the support library to the dependencies section. For example, to add the v4 support library, add the following lines:
>
>    dependencies {
>          ...
>          compile "com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.+"
>      }